# Relationship between the notions of "excellent ring" and "universally catenary Nagata ring"

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Every excellent ring is both universally catenary and Nagata.  How "close" is a universally catenary Nagata ring to being excellent?

**Context:** I have not worked very much with the notions described above.  While I certainly would not turn down a counterexample, I am more interested in getting an idea of how these notions are used in practice, and when it is appropriate to use one versus the other.

Comment: In this article by Christel Rotthaus, she constructs a three-dimensional regular local ring which is Nagata (universally Japanese) but not excellent.  Perhaps it will give you some idea of how hard one must work for such examples.  http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002418517

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't speak a word of German, but thanks for the reference in any case.

Answer (score 4):

Nishimura in "[A few examples of local rings, I](https://doi.org/10.1215/21562261-1503754)" constructs a two-dimensional normal Nagata domain that is not analytically normal, and hence not excellent (Example 2.5). Since this example is a normal two-dimensional ring, it is Cohen–Macaulay, and therefore is universally catenary by Theorem 17.9 in [Matsumura](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139171762).

Nishimura attributes the construction to Rotthaus, citing [the paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01214184) referenced by Graham Leuschke [in the comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82403/relationship-between-the-notions-of-excellent-ring-and-universally-catenary-n#comment211768_82403).